# Angular Material and layout-fill to fill up to 100% of screen, no more

Tags: css, angularjs, less, material-design, angular-material

I'm looking into Angular Material but I'm not used to using `flexbox` for layouts. I don't want a scrollbar on the right of my screen. However, I want to have a scrollbar on the right side of each `div` the beneath the toolbar.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainController as main" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-include="'menu.html'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'toolbar.html'"></div>
  <div ui-view layout="row" layout-fill></div>
</body>
```

[My Plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAXENq7rcXcD3z1iqMx4?p=preview)

In my Plunkr, notice there are two toolbars showing. I don't want the outer toolbar to show. If I scroll down in the inner left scroll, I can't see the bottom of that element unless I scroll farther down using the outer right scroll.

[Another example of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtrfJ.jpg)

In my Imgur example, I have scrolled down the document and I can see everything, but I can't see the toolbar anymore. For some reason, `md-toolbar` is the amount that is added to the height. I can fix this with setting body height to 95% but that is not a very good solution.

Comment: I dont get your problem even after checking screen shot

Comment: I don't want a scrollbar to the right. The layout is more then the wholescreen.

Comment: can you post the screen shot of what you need?

Comment: I updated the post: http://imgur.com/a/3eEJH

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this question, as I have the same issue?

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33933197/2024913 I answered by own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like setting `position: fixed; right: 0;` on the element solved this for me.